# Set the minimum TLS version as 1.2 for API Gateway

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have api gateway for lambda such as

```
https://x6c5e11xkc.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/prod/c
```

Now I want to set this TLS for more than 1.2 only.

I found the document here below, but I am not sure what the custom-domain... my url is custom-domain???

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-custom-domain-tls-version.html

Where should I set??

my curl response is here

```
$curl -s -v --tlsv1.1  https://x6c5e11xkc.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/prod/c

*   Trying 65.9.17.XX:443...
* Connected to x6c5e11xkc.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com (65.9.17.49) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: none
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / AEAD-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com
*  start date: Sep 27 00:00:00 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Oct 26 23:59:59 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "x6c5e11xkc.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com" matched cert's "*.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Amazon; OU=Server CA 1B; CN=Amazon
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multiplexing
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x11f80b600)
> GET /prod/c HTTP/2
> Host: x6c5e11xkc.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com
> user-agent: curl/7.79.1
> accept: */*
> 
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!

< HTTP/2 400 
< content-type: application/json
< content-length: 0
< date: Thu, 26 May 2022 02:41:55 GMT
< x-amzn-requestid: 73059bd5-7dae-4366-9a43-22fa50a331f2
< x-amz-apigw-id: StlUpHXeNjMFlww=
< x-amzn-trace-id: Root=1-628ee8ea-4bac852e062cd9bc28c64bf8;Sampled=0
< x-cache: Error from cloudfront
< via: 1.1 1eb001a93e05e8dbbe3865b069b8c264.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
< x-amz-cf-pop: BKK50-C1
< x-amz-cf-id: T3RAkLW5HAdfnuxcVXlRHniwdNiI2JMyMzPxkAqcof1AkMTmJ7r0TQ==
<
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom domain is the domain you own like mydomain.com and you can set on API Gateway console, on top of that, you can use ACM(AWS Certificate Manager) to be assigned to that custom domain by applying the TLS policy you want (1.0 or 1,2 is preferred ), so navigate to ACM and create a certificate for your domain, and then assign it to the custom domain.

**Create ACM certificate**

[image: Create ACM certificate]

**Create Custom domain and assign an ACM Certificate**

[image: Create Custom domain and assign an ACM Certificate]

Finally, Select the API Mappings Tab and configure the API mappings, select API and stage.

**API Mappings**
[image: API Mappings]

Make sure that you configure your DNS to point to the API Gateway Domain name, you can use Route53 for example and add a new A (ALIAS) record.

Regarding TLS,is backwards compatible which means After upgrading the default to 1.2, systems using 1.1 and 1.0 will continue to function, so if any of your processing requires 1.0 and 1.1, it will remain available. Nevertheless, it’s recommended that developers upgrade the code to run on TLS 1.2 only.

I hope this information may be helpful

Comment: Thank you very much I understand the custam-domain name.It's quite helpful for my nextstep!! However in my case I am thinking use outside domain name for this, Can I find what the minimum version of TLS for Non custom-domain name??

Comment: Hello, :) you are welcome, AWS is providing an API Gateway endpoint which already includes good practices on TLS, for sure you can analyze in detail what kind of TLS they are using, although, in my understanding, there’s no actions from your side in this case

Comment: thank you very much. I tried `echo | openssl s_client -connect x6c5e11xkc.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com:443 -tls1_1`  works, so ,,,Tls1.1 is alive and there is no way to block this without making `custom-domain` name??

Comment: @whitebear TLS is backward compatible, which means if the default TLS version is 1.2, systems using 1.0 and 1.1 will continue to function, I hope this information help you to get a conclusion

Comment: Thank you I understood. My goal is shutdown the 1.1 access, so I will use custom-domain for that purpose. I mark this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

> not sure what the custom-domain

This is **your own domain that you bought** for your api, e.g. `api.myapp.com`. Only if you have your own domain associated with the API Gateway you can control its TLS settings.

Domain `https://kfskdfs.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/prod/webhook` is owned by AWS, thus you have no control over its SSL certificates nor any associated settings.

Comment: I see,,thank you for your comment! I still have one question, If I try to use `v1.1` by `curl` but it returns `SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / AEAD-AES128-GCM-SHA256` message, does it mean v1.1 connection is changed to v1.3 connection automatically?? or Gateway still accept TLSv1.1 access?

Comment: @whitebear I'm not sure what curl is doing.

Comment: Thank you very much I tried with openssl  `echo | openssl s_client -connect x6c5e11xkc.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com:443 -tls1_1` and it works unfortunately.... So maybe i must set the custom-domain to block the `TLS1.1`.